# Change theme of angular library when imported

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass

I'm trying to do something specific but can't find any information about it.
What I'm trying to do is make a common angular library with my styled components (size, font, ..) and then import this library in 2 different projects, so far so good.

But now I want the 2 projects to have different color/font/icon themes.
So I need a way to define the theme in the parent projects, and then gets applied to the styling of the library components.

This way al my components in the library can stay the same (single code base) and it can be used in different applications with there house style.

Is there a way to do this?

Kind regards,
P90K

Answer (score 1):

## Create an Angular Library

To create a Angular library you can follow the guide [here](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries). You've to publish it on `npm` and install on your projects.

## Style your Library

### 1. Change Style Encapulation with `ViewEncapsulation`

[Read More](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation)

Defines template and style encapsulation options available for Component’s `Component`. By using `ViewEncapsulation.None` you are exposing your styles to outer components.

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
...
})
```

**Note**: This can help to override any component CSS but be sure to use proper selectors

### 2. Use `:host`

[Read More](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/)

The `host` can help to override CSS without touching the view encapsulations.

> CSS pseudo-class function selects the shadow host of the [shadow
> DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) containing the CSS it is used inside

**Lib in your parent template**

```
<your-component class="custom-component-cls"></your-component>
```

**Lib style in your parent style**

```
:host{
    ::ng-deep .custom-component-cls{
        color: white;
    }
}
```